# DistanceMatrixService give different distance from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using Google Maps `DistanceMatrixService()` to get the directions and distance between 2 points in GoogleMaps. However, the result I get from the service is slightly different from the one shown by on the GoogleMaps web site.

I'm getting 4km when the website shows 3km.

I know it can have difference when using Places instead of the actual address, but I'm using coordinates in both, api and website, and the result is still different.

This is my code:

```
//Just for example
var origin = '-27.5970141,-48.5614466';
var destination = '-27.5927353,-48.5556316';

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    }, callback);
```

These coordinates on the [map gives a distance](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/-27.596424,-48.5597757/-27.58677,-48.5432619/@-27.5905072,-48.5577428,15.75z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0) of 3,1km and on the service request is 4,8 km.

What do I need to do to get the actual distance?

---

***Edit***

While doing some tests, I noticed I can get the proper distance by passing the full address instead of the coordinates. But this gives me 2 problems:

- 1: Usually I have access only to the coordinates, because of the it's easy to store/get the information (would have to change some core code of the system to get the full address);
- 2: When dealing with places where the address reference to a big location, for example, a University, where the address is huge, the start point isn't always where it was supposed to be. So I keep getting the wrong location and wrong distance.

Comment: The 4.8 km is a round-a-bout route due to the origin being on the "wrong" side of the bridge (it does look like the "coordinates" as strings are returning the exact same result).  Do you really want "driving" distance?  Would a walking distance work?

Comment: Google recommends using place_id instead of coordinates for more accurate results

Answer (score 3):

quoted strings containing numbers are not "coordinates" (strings are sent to the geocoder, and will result in a location that is the closest "known" address), use a google.maps.LatLng or google.maps.LatLngLiteral for coordinates.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixRequest):

> **destinations** Type:  Array<(string|LatLng|Place)>
>
> An array containing destination **address strings**, or LatLng, or Place objects, to which to calculate distance and time. Required.
>
> **origins** Type:  Array<(string|LatLng|Place)>
>
> An array containing origin **address strings**, or LatLng, or Place objects, from which to calculate distance and time. Required.

```
//Just for example
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.5970141,-48.5614466);
var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.5927353,-48.5556316);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
}, callback);
```

Comment: Based on your comment and answer, I tried to do as you said, but I'm getting the same result. I even tried with different locations and coordinates, but I always end up with the same type of result. When using coordinates, the distance is always different. Only by using the full address I can get the proper distance, but there is thos 2 problems I mentioned on the question.